# how to redirect a method in a sequence diagram

Tags: java, uml

I have a little problem with my sequence diagram.

I would like to redirect the a method from the instance h to g if iddHoraire happen.

Something like redirect getAll()  .

In reality if the schedule is added the user will be redirect to the list of shchedule

thank you for the answer

Here is my sequence diagram :[image: sequnce diagram]